# jquery find a li in a list with a class and then get the text of that li

Tags: jquery, list, class, find

I 'm trying to find an element with a class and then get the text within that li to place it in another list

```
 <div id="list-container">
     <ul class="list">
         <li class="selected">text1</li>
         <li>text2</li>
         <li>text3</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="list">
         <li class="selected">text4</li>
         <li>text5</li>
         <li>text6</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="list">
         <li class="selected">text7</li>
         <li>text8</li>
         <li>text9</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="listOfSlected"></div>
```

and what has happened to me is something like this

```
    $('#list-container .selected').each(function(index) {
        var actual = $('this');
        var text = actual.html();


        $('#listOfSlected').html(function() {
            return "<li>" + text + "</li>";
        });
    });
```

applying this code I get undefined

Answer (score 1):

The variable, `text` is undefined, because the selector `$('this')` is searching for an element named `<this>`. The keyword `this` isn't a string.

Remove the quotes, and change:

```
var actual = $('this');
```

to:

```
var actual = $(this);
```

---

Additionally, the problem with your code is that you are replacing the HTML of `#listOfSlected` on each iteration. Thus, only the last element's text is shown, in this case 'text7'.

I think you are looking to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the element's text instead:

```
$('#list-container .selected').each(function () {
    $('#listOfSlected').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
});
```

```js
$('#list-container .selected').each(function () {
    $('#listOfSlected').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list-container">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="selected">text1</li>
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="selected">text4</li>
        <li>text5</li>
        <li>text6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="selected">text7</li>
        <li>text8</li>
        <li>text9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul id="listOfSlected"></ul>
```